# Blank error dialogue importing graph built in neo4j 2.2 into Gephi 0.8.2

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I have built a graph in Neo4j 2.2.0. I have validated it by using Cypher interface querying etc. Now I want to import it into Gephi 0.8.2. I am using neo4j plugin (not sure of its version. Its downloaded through the tool)

When I try importing my neo4j database it gives blank error popup, no information on it. I tried to import defaultdb which comes with neo4j, the exact same behavior. So I suppose its not to do with database but some configuration or version etc.

I also enabled debugging option in etc conf setting of Gephi.

```
-J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea
```

But this is not opening or printing anything. I also tries to find Gephi log file which I cannot. Could not find anything of google. Any idea what may be going on or how to debug/ see log file etc? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You want to try the following in Gephi
1. Go to Tools - > Plugins - > Updates
2. Select all the plugins listed and click update

Comment: 1) Did not find link for Gephi 1. 2) Dont understand how it'll solve the problem? Is this something you experienced and fixed before?

Comment: Yes. I had similar issues and got it resolved. I tried few steps and got it resolved. Also open Gephi (not Gephi 1 - its a typo) and follow the steps.

Comment: Gephi 0.8.2, neo4j 2.2.0-RC01. JDK 7u75.All plugins updated. Still not workng.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get around this obstacle. 
you can export your data from Neo4j to a CSV file, and then upload the file to Gephi.

hope it gets you what you need.

Comment: I did not find any way to export csv data from neo4j. And I feel there is no need of that for me as I already have CSV files. Just wanted to check if it can happen seamless without me having to import/export.